# Riwaka Hops: Where to get 'em

Tags: hops

Anyone know where to obtain some Riwaka hops in bulk?  I'm itching to try them, but internet searches are coming up dry for me.

Comment: These hops look awesome. I hope a solid answer shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: http://www.nzhops.co.nz/varieties/riwaka.html
It will depend on where you live in the world as to whether they will ship them to you.
You'll have to give them a call to arrange for bulk quantities.
Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

It never hurts to ping your local homebrew shop about rare items like this.  For instance, Austin Homebrew once ordered Riwaka in bulk, back in 2008.  Of course, they didn't last long, and I don't think they ever reordered that variety.

Riwaka is also called "D Saaz," so you can try searching for that term.  I found them in 3-ounce bags at http://www.pubshop.com.au/shop/details.asp?PID=1006.

EDIT:
Looks like they're out of stock at pubshop, but Grain and Grape does have them in stock.  http://www.grainandgrape.com.au/product_info.php?products_id=8883

Comment: Yeah, our local shop has some rare hops, like Nelson, but none of the others I'm looking for right now.